# HSQLDB INSERT/SELECT across multiple databases

Tags: jdbc, sql-insert, hsqldb

HSQLDB allows insertion of data from a query (or table) into another table like this:

```
INSERT INTO dest SELECT * FROM source;
```

Now what if I access two databases from a Java application, each over a separate connection, and `dest` is in one while `source` is in the other? Do I have to do everything by hand (run the `SELECT` query on `source`, iterate over the result set and insert each record into `dest`), or is there a shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no shortcut.

You can write a method that uses getObject() for the column values from rows of a ResultSet and sets the parameters of a PreparedStatement before calling addBatch() for each row and executeBatch() at the end.